# SQL Server Update Permissions

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I'm currently working with SQL Server 2008 R2, and I have only `READ` access to a few tables that house production data.

I'm finding that in many cases, it would be extremely nice if I could run something like the following, and get the total record count back that was affected :

```
USE DB
GO

BEGIN TRANSACTION
UPDATE Person
SET pType = 'retailer'
WHERE pTrackId = 20 
AND pWebId LIKE 'rtlr%';

ROLLBACK TRANSACTION
```

However, seeing as I don't have the `UPDATE` permission, I cannot successfully run this script without getting :

```
Msg 229, Level 14, State 5, Line 5
The UPDATE permission was denied on the object 'Person', database 'DB', schema 'dbo'.
```

**My questions :**

- Is there any way that my account in SQL Server can be configured so that if I want to run an `UPDATE` script, it would automatically be wrapped in a transaction with an rollback (so no data is actually affected)

I know I could make a copy of that data and run my script against a local SSMS instance, but I'm wondering if there is a permission-based way of accomplishing this.

Comment: I edited my question to be more centered around a user-permission based solution. I'd like to have the piece of mind that our IT team can run the exact same query but have it actually affect the data set... if there just isn't a way to do that, then that will suffice as an answer as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to bypass SQL Server permissions. And I don't think it's a good idea to develop on production database anyway. It would be much better to have development version of the database you work with.

---

If the number of affected rows is all you need then you can run select instead of update.

For example:

```
select count(*)
from Person
where pTrackId = 20 
AND pWebId LIKE 'rtlr%';
```

Comment: When pulling from production data, I also like to add a `WITH(NOLOCK)` to the `FROM`

Answer (score 3):

If you are only after the amount of rows that would be affected with this update, that would be same amount of rows that currently comply to the `WHERE` clause.

So you can just run a `SELECT` statement as such:

```
SELECT COUNT(pType) 
FROM Person WHERE pTrackId = 20 
AND pWebId LIKE 'rtlr%';
```

And you'd get the resulting potential rows affected.

Comment: This would only count rows where `pType` is not null. There's no such condition in the OP's UPDATE statement, so this could return an incorrect result.

Answer (score 0):

> 1.First Login as admin in sqlserver
>   2.Goto login->your name->Check the roles.
>   3.IF u have write access,then you can accomplish the above task.
>   4.If not make sure you grant access to write.

Answer (score 0):

If it's strictly necessary to try the update, you could write a stored procedure, accepting dynamic SQL as a string (Your UPDATE query) and wrapping the dynamic SQL in a transaction context which is then rolled back. Your account could then be granted access to that stored procedure.

Personally, I think that's a terrible idea, and incredibly unsafe - some queries break out of such transaction contexts (e.g. ALTER TABLE). You may be able to block those somehow, but it would still be a security/auditing problem.

I recommend writing a query to count the relevant rows:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM --tables
WHERE --your where clause
-- any other clauses here e.g. GROUP BY, HAVING ...
```

Comment: If you think adding the update to a stored proc is a terrible idea, then please don't suggest it.

Comment: @valverij It's a valid answer - just not one I'd recommend. I gave reasons why I wouldn't recommend it, hopefully enabling people to come to their own conclusions. Not to mention, any self-respecting DBA wouldn't allow such a thing on their production environments, so I don't think it will happen. tl;dr: answer != suggestion IMO.

Comment: The dynamic query suggestion wouldn't actually work. The EXECUTE permission wouldn't apply to the dynamic query and you would still get the same error about permissions denied. Try it and see for yourself.